# Jquery input mask plugin for decimal number

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

Hei !

i have check input masks on this link http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ 
but i want something onblur when user leave textbox then it validate whether the format is 999,99 if user has not typed 999,99 then it display message to correct it. otherwise not .can anyone give a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Stuvie got something :)

http://jsfiddle.net/g8KSg/8/

```
$('input').focusout(function(e){
    var error = false;
    var regex = /^\d+,\d{2,2}$/;

    if(!($('#checkval').val().match(regex))) {   
        error = true;
    }

    if(error == true) {
            $('#result').html("<em>ERROR</em> Input must be deciaml format '99,00'");
        } else {
            $('#result').html("");
        }

});
```

Comment: nice but can we restrict like 999,00 . shud nt allow 9999,00

Comment: user shud type just 456,00 but should not 45777,00

Comment: Jeg mener at det må være mint en tall foran , comma  .Det må ikke være blank foran komma . For eksempel brukeren kunne ikke skrive sånn ,99 .Det bør være sånn 99,99 eller 999,99

Comment: Just change the 3,3 to 2,2 like `var regex2 = /^\d{2,2},\d{2,2}$/;`

Comment: Takk for forteller alltid riktig svar men ikke andre ;)

Comment: if we want just minimum one before comma then wht wud be regex, one could write as 9,00 or 999999,00

Comment: `var regex = /,\d{2,2}$/;` sets that it must contain a comma, and two numbers as last chars ... see http://jsfiddle.net/g8KSg/13/

Comment: but also 1 character atleast before , i want

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery on its own you can achieve what you want using regular expressions. It may not be as nice to work with but regular expressions can be pretty powerful...

```
// either create a hidden error message in the HTML 
// or create an error message element here...
var numberMaskError = $(".number-mask-error");
var numberMaskInput = $(".number-mask");

function validateNumberMask() {
   // using a regular expression to determine validity
   // matches a pattern with one or more digits 0-9 followed by a comma
   // followed by exactly two more digits 0-9
   if(numberMaskInput.val().search(/^\d+,\d{2,2}$/) !== -1) {
     // hide or remove the error
     numberMaskError.hide();
   } else {
     // show or append the error
     numberMaskError.show();
   }
}

numberMaskInput.bind("change", function() {
  // validate the field when the value has been changed on blur
  validateNumberMask();
}).bind("keyup", function() {
  // revalidate if the error is currently showing and user is changing the value
  if(err.is(":visible")) {
    validateNumberMask();
  }
});
```

I hope this helps

Comment: whts regex for this type 99,00